# How to sort elements from a 2D array above the main diagonal

Tags: c++, c

Without any use of in-built functions, libraries or pointers how can I sort elements from an 2D array above the main diagonal.

I really couldn't find any explanation or on other sites. I tried to change the 2D array into a 1D array and then sort but couldn't find the logic behind the code.

For example in a 4x4 array:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

To print:

```
 1 12  8  7
 5  6  4  3 
 9 10 11  2
13 14 15 16
```

Comment: I'm not exactly clear, how is the second one sorted? Only difference is between position of 2 and 6.

Comment: For example if its an 4x4 2D array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 It should print 1 12 8 7 5 6 4 3 9 10 11 2 13 14 15 16. Sorry for this i cant format it.

Comment: But what is the logic behind the sorting? That doesn't seem sorted to me.

Comment: Sort the elements above the main diagonal in a descending way i edited it in the question sorry for any problems should have made an larger 2D array.

Comment: What diagonal ?

Comment: The elements above the main diagonal.

Comment: There is some strange mapping going on, where you map all elements above the main diagonal into linear order. The order seems to be: first the elements from the first row from left to right, then the second row from left to right and so on. Once you have this order, write proper accessor function and you can sort them.

Comment: So essentially you're asking us to write a sorting algorithm from scratch for you? Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: When asking a question, you should show some effort of what you tried so far and where you struggle. Read [ask]!

Comment: No i dont want you write the sorting algorithm from scratch thats my part :D . Just want some brainstorm ideas about how it could be done.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discussion forum, it's for specific questions and answers.

Comment: @melpomene I wrote the algorithm but the question is on hold where could i post the answer if someone wants to review it ?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic, though your question is strange without an algorithm, I tried to reopen it, and if succeed, you can write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the details of actually writing the algorithm, here's an example of an approach to breaking down and solving this problem:

1. Iterate through the 2D array and figure out which values are 'above' the main diagonal.  Store these values in a data structure (probably a 1D array)
2. Sort that resulting array (I'm assuming you have learned how to sort an array, but let me know if this step is a problem)
3. Build a new 2D array using these sorted elements, and find a way to put the sorted elements back into the correct spot, with everything on and below the main diagonal maintaining their old spots. (hint: is there a map from sorted element index to where on the upper diagonal of the 2D array it would go?)

Hopefully this will help you writing this algorithm!  Let me know if I misunderstood something about the problem or if you have questions.

Comment: For step 2: use `std::sort` or `qsort` (depending on whether you write C++ or C. No need to re-invent the wheel ...

Comment: Agreed with @chtz.  In particular, figure out what you want from the algorithm, and then figure out the best way to do it (using libraries and previously built functions when possible!)

Answer (score -2):

I have used 4 loops. The inner 2 loops  find max element, the outer 2 loops place the maximum element to the convenient cell.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {
    false = 0,
    true = 1
}bool;

int x[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
bool change = false;

int main()
{
    int a , b;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4; k++){
        for(int l = k + 1; l < 4 ; l++){
            int max = x[k][l];
            for(int m = k; m < 4; m++){
                for(int n = l; n < 4; n++){
                    if(x[m][n] > max){
                        max = x[m][n];
                        a = m;
                        b = n;
                        change = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(change)
            {
                x[a][b] = x[k][l];
                x[k][l] = max;
                change = false;
            }
        }
    }

for (int o = 0; o < 4 ; o++){
    for(int u = 0; u < 4; u++){
        printf("%d ",x[o][u]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I literally have the same result as you, except where the numbers 11 and 16 are it shows me memory addresses. Numbers 11 and 16 should stay on the main diagonal.

Comment: Code-only answers have an unfortunate tendency to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You may be able to salvage this answer by explaining what you are doing and why. I also strongly recommend using descriptive variable names. This often reduces the amount of explaining you have to do. Note that because this code has been written to make it hard to read, I have not read the code. It could be completely bogus for all I know, hence the "may" in "You may be able to salvage."

Comment: Does not work for, e.g., `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,12,8},{9,10,11,7},{13,14,15,16}}`